# how to use image as a canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a script which I'm using to draw rectangles on a canvas. The user can drag/reposition the drawn rectangles and also add new ones by double-clicking. Now I want to add an image on the background that is, I don't want to use a plain canvas but instead an image on which I can place my rectangles.

What I am trying to build is these rectangles correspond to particular regions of the images. Once this images and rectangles are loaded, if the regions and rectangles are not aligned, the user should be able to reposition them correctly.

Here is my code:

```js
//Box object to hold data for all drawn rects
function Box() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.w = 1; // default width and height?
  this.h = 1;
  this.fill = '#444444';
}

//Initialize a new Box, add it, and invalidate the canvas
function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill) {
  var rect = new Box;
  rect.x = x;
  rect.y = y;
  rect.w = w
  rect.h = h;
  rect.fill = fill;
  boxes.push(rect);
  invalidate();
}

// holds all our rectangles
var boxes = []; 

var canvas;
var ctx;
var WIDTH;
var HEIGHT;
var INTERVAL = 20;  // how often, in milliseconds, we check to see if a redraw is needed

var isDrag = false;
var mx, my; // mouse coordinates

 // when set to true, the canvas will redraw everything
 // invalidate() just sets this to false right now
 // we want to call invalidate() whenever we make a change
var canvasValid = false;

// The node (if any) being selected.
// If in the future we want to select multiple objects, this will get turned into an array
var mySel; 

// The selection color and width. Right now we have a red selection with a small width
var mySelColor = '#CC0000';
var mySelWidth = 2;

// we use a fake canvas to draw individual shapes for selection testing
var ghostcanvas;
var gctx; // fake canvas context

// since we can drag from anywhere in a node
// instead of just its x/y corner, we need to save
// the offset of the mouse when we start dragging.
var offsetx, offsety;

// Padding and border style widths for mouse offsets
var stylePaddingLeft, stylePaddingTop, styleBorderLeft, styleBorderTop;


// initialize our canvas, add a ghost canvas, set draw loop
// then add everything we want to intially exist on the canvas

function init() {
  // canvas = fill_canvas();
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  HEIGHT = canvas.height;
  WIDTH = canvas.width;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ghostcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ghostcanvas.height = HEIGHT;
  ghostcanvas.width = WIDTH;
  gctx = ghostcanvas.getContext('2d');
  
  //fixes a problem where double clicking causes text to get selected on the canvas
  canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
  
  // fixes mouse co-ordinate problems when there's a border or padding
  // see getMouse for more detail
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10)      || 0;
    stylePaddingTop  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10)       || 0;
    styleBorderLeft  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10)  || 0;
    styleBorderTop   = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10)   || 0;
  }
  
  // make draw() fire every INTERVAL milliseconds
  setInterval(draw, INTERVAL);
  
  // set our events. Up and down are for dragging,
  // double click is for making new boxes
  canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
  canvas.ondblclick = myDblClick;
  
  // add custom initialization here:
  
  // add an orange rectangle
  addRect(200, 200, 200, 200, '#FFC02B');
  
  // add a smaller blue rectangle
  addRect(25, 90, 250, 150  , '#2BB8FF');
}

//wipes the canvas context
function clear(c) {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

// While draw is called as often as the INTERVAL variable demands,
// It only ever does something if the canvas gets invalidated by our code
function draw() {
  if (canvasValid == false) {
    clear(ctx);
    
    // Add stuff you want drawn in the background all the time here
    
    // draw all boxes
    var l = boxes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        drawshape(ctx, boxes[i], boxes[i].fill);
    }
    
    // draw selection
    // right now this is just a stroke along the edge of the selected box
    if (mySel != null) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = mySelColor;
      ctx.lineWidth = mySelWidth;
      ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x,mySel.y,mySel.w,mySel.h);
    }
    
    // Add stuff you want drawn on top all the time here
    
    
    canvasValid = true;
  }
}

// Draws a single shape to a single context
// draw() will call this with the normal canvas
// myDown will call this with the ghost canvas
function drawshape(context, shape, fill) {
  context.fillStyle = fill;
  
  // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
  if (shape.x > WIDTH || shape.y > HEIGHT) return; 
  if (shape.x + shape.w < 0 || shape.y + shape.h < 0) return;
  
  context.fillRect(shape.x,shape.y,shape.w,shape.h);
}

// Happens when the mouse is moving inside the canvas
function myMove(e){
  if (isDrag){
    getMouse(e);
    
    mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
    mySel.y = my - offsety;   
    
    // something is changing position so we better invalidate the canvas!
    invalidate();
  }
}

// Happens when the mouse is clicked in the canvas
function myDown(e){
  getMouse(e);
  clear(gctx);
  var l = boxes.length;
  for (var i = l-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // draw shape onto ghost context
    drawshape(gctx, boxes[i], 'black');
    
    // get image data at the mouse x,y pixel
    var imageData = gctx.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1);
    var index = (mx + my * imageData.width) * 4;
    
    // if the mouse pixel exists, select and break
    if (imageData.data[3] > 0) {
      mySel = boxes[i];
      offsetx = mx - mySel.x;
      offsety = my - mySel.y;
      mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
      mySel.y = my - offsety;
      isDrag = true;
      canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
      invalidate();
      clear(gctx);
      return;
    }
    
  }
  // havent returned means we have selected nothing
  mySel = null;
  // clear the ghost canvas for next time
  clear(gctx);
  // invalidate because we might need the selection border to disappear
  invalidate();
}

function myUp(){
  isDrag = false;
  canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

// adds a new node
function myDblClick(e) {
  getMouse(e);
  // for this method width and height determine the starting X and Y, too.
  // so I left them as vars in case someone wanted to make them args for something and copy this code
  var width = 150;
  var height = 100;
  addRect(mx - (width / 2), my - (height / 2), width, height, '#77DD44');
}

function invalidate() {
  canvasValid = false;
}

// Sets mx,my to the mouse position relative to the canvas
// unfortunately this can be tricky, we have to worry about padding and borders
function getMouse(e) {
      var element = canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;

      if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
          offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
          offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
      }

      // Add padding and border style widths to offset
      offsetX += stylePaddingLeft;
      offsetY += stylePaddingTop;

      offsetX += styleBorderLeft;
      offsetY += styleBorderTop;

      mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
      my = e.pageY - offsetY
}

// If you dont want to use <body onLoad='init()'>
// You could uncomment this init() reference and place the script reference inside the body tag
init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>js</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
   </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below should work if an image is loaded in the html.

Changes in the code are two:

- loading the image into a variable
- drawing the image onto the canvas using `ctx.drawImage(im, 0, 0)`

```js
//Box object to hold data for all drawn rects
function Box() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.w = 1; // default width and height?
  this.h = 1;
  this.fill = '#444444';
}

//Initialize a new Box, add it, and invalidate the canvas
function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill) {
  var rect = new Box;
  rect.x = x;
  rect.y = y;
  rect.w = w
  rect.h = h;
  rect.fill = fill;
  boxes.push(rect);
  invalidate();
}

//***************************
// This will load the image into the variable "im"
var im = document.getElementById("myImage");
//***************************

// holds all our rectangles
var boxes = []; 

var canvas;
var ctx;
var WIDTH;
var HEIGHT;
var INTERVAL = 20;  // how often, in milliseconds, we check to see if a redraw is needed

var isDrag = false;
var mx, my; // mouse coordinates

 // when set to true, the canvas will redraw everything
 // invalidate() just sets this to false right now
 // we want to call invalidate() whenever we make a change
var canvasValid = false;

// The node (if any) being selected.
// If in the future we want to select multiple objects, this will get turned into an array
var mySel; 

// The selection color and width. Right now we have a red selection with a small width
var mySelColor = '#CC0000';
var mySelWidth = 2;

// we use a fake canvas to draw individual shapes for selection testing
var ghostcanvas;
var gctx; // fake canvas context

// since we can drag from anywhere in a node
// instead of just its x/y corner, we need to save
// the offset of the mouse when we start dragging.
var offsetx, offsety;

// Padding and border style widths for mouse offsets
var stylePaddingLeft, stylePaddingTop, styleBorderLeft, styleBorderTop;


// initialize our canvas, add a ghost canvas, set draw loop
// then add everything we want to intially exist on the canvas

function init() {
  // canvas = fill_canvas();
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  HEIGHT = canvas.height;
  WIDTH = canvas.width;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ghostcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ghostcanvas.height = HEIGHT;
  ghostcanvas.width = WIDTH;
  gctx = ghostcanvas.getContext('2d');
  
  //fixes a problem where double clicking causes text to get selected on the canvas
  canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
  
  // fixes mouse co-ordinate problems when there's a border or padding
  // see getMouse for more detail
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10)      || 0;
    stylePaddingTop  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10)       || 0;
    styleBorderLeft  = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10)  || 0;
    styleBorderTop   = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10)   || 0;
  }
  
  // make draw() fire every INTERVAL milliseconds
  setInterval(draw, INTERVAL);
  
  // set our events. Up and down are for dragging,
  // double click is for making new boxes
  canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
  canvas.ondblclick = myDblClick;
  
  // add custom initialization here:
  
  // add an orange rectangle
  addRect(200, 200, 200, 200, '#FFC02B');
  
  // add a smaller blue rectangle
  addRect(25, 90, 250, 150  , '#2BB8FF');
}

//wipes the canvas context
function clear(c) {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

// While draw is called as often as the INTERVAL variable demands,
// It only ever does something if the canvas gets invalidated by our code
function draw() {
  if (canvasValid == false) {
    clear(ctx);
    
    // Add stuff you want drawn in the background all the time here
    
    // draw all boxes
    var l = boxes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        drawshape(ctx, boxes[i], boxes[i].fill);
    }
    
    // draw selection
    // right now this is just a stroke along the edge of the selected box
    if (mySel != null) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = mySelColor;
      ctx.lineWidth = mySelWidth;
      ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x,mySel.y,mySel.w,mySel.h);
    }
    
    // Add stuff you want drawn on top all the time here
    //You might want to change the size of the image
    //In that case use ctx.drawImage(im,0,0,width,height);
    //***************************
    ctx.drawImage(im,0,0);
    //***************************
    
    canvasValid = true;
  }
}

// Draws a single shape to a single context
// draw() will call this with the normal canvas
// myDown will call this with the ghost canvas
function drawshape(context, shape, fill) {
  context.fillStyle = fill;
  
  // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
  if (shape.x > WIDTH || shape.y > HEIGHT) return; 
  if (shape.x + shape.w < 0 || shape.y + shape.h < 0) return;
  
  context.fillRect(shape.x,shape.y,shape.w,shape.h);
}

// Happens when the mouse is moving inside the canvas
function myMove(e){
  if (isDrag){
    getMouse(e);
    
    mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
    mySel.y = my - offsety;   
    
    // something is changing position so we better invalidate the canvas!
    invalidate();
  }
}

// Happens when the mouse is clicked in the canvas
function myDown(e){
  getMouse(e);
  clear(gctx);
  var l = boxes.length;
  for (var i = l-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // draw shape onto ghost context
    drawshape(gctx, boxes[i], 'black');
    
    // get image data at the mouse x,y pixel
    var imageData = gctx.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1);
    var index = (mx + my * imageData.width) * 4;
    
    // if the mouse pixel exists, select and break
    if (imageData.data[3] > 0) {
      mySel = boxes[i];
      offsetx = mx - mySel.x;
      offsety = my - mySel.y;
      mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
      mySel.y = my - offsety;
      isDrag = true;
      canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
      invalidate();
      clear(gctx);
      return;
    }
    
  }
  // havent returned means we have selected nothing
  mySel = null;
  // clear the ghost canvas for next time
  clear(gctx);
  // invalidate because we might need the selection border to disappear
  invalidate();
}

function myUp(){
  isDrag = false;
  canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

// adds a new node
function myDblClick(e) {
  getMouse(e);
  // for this method width and height determine the starting X and Y, too.
  // so I left them as vars in case someone wanted to make them args for something and copy this code
  var width = 150;
  var height = 100;
  addRect(mx - (width / 2), my - (height / 2), width, height, '#77DD44');
}

function invalidate() {
  canvasValid = false;
}

// Sets mx,my to the mouse position relative to the canvas
// unfortunately this can be tricky, we have to worry about padding and borders
function getMouse(e) {
      var element = canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;

      if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
          offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
          offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
      }

      // Add padding and border style widths to offset
      offsetX += stylePaddingLeft;
      offsetY += stylePaddingTop;

      offsetX += styleBorderLeft;
      offsetY += styleBorderTop;

      mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
      my = e.pageY - offsetY
}

// If you dont want to use <body onLoad='init()'>
// You could uncomment this init() reference and place the script reference inside the body tag
init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>js</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
   </canvas>
   
<!-- This image will be displayed on the canvas -->   
<img id="myImage" src="image.jpg" style = "display: none">


</body>
</html>
```